# adding some clases to array and looping them through this array?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to push a class to an empty array . then use for to loop through classes in this array but it is not working. is there another way to loop through classes?nothing return in the console , no errors shown

```
let a=[]
class push_array{
  constructor (first , second) {
    this.first=first;
    this.second=second
    function pushing(){
      a.push(this)
      pushing()
      console.log(a)
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
const result=new push_array('fdsfs','fdsfdsf')
```

Comment: `pushing` isn’t referenced by anything; the function is discarded right away. You also never attempt to call this function initially. If it was referenced somewhere, calling it would result in a stack overflow error and the `console.log` would be unreachable. I don’t see where you attempt to loop anything.

Comment: The answer below is correct but it's a little weird what you are trying to do. Modifying the variable `a` which is outside of the scope of the class is a little weird and may indicate a data structure issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pushing` is called from within `pushing`, so the logic that pushes the instance to the array is never executed.

```js
let a = []
class push_array {
  constructor(first, second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    a.push(this);
  }
}

const result = new push_array('fdsfs', 'fdsfdsf');
console.log(a);
```

Its unclear what your goal is, but using variable outside of a `class` could make your code complex very fast. If you're storing the result, why not just push the object to the array after instantiating?

```js
let a = []

class push_array {
  constructor(first, second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
  }
}

const result = new push_array('fdsfs', 'fdsfdsf');
a.push(result);

console.log(a);
```